# How do I run a function until the expected value is returned?

Tags: go

I want to run a function until it returns 0.

```
value, _ := FuncX()

if value != 0 {
                    value, _ := FuncX()
                  if(value != 0) {
                     value, _ := FuncX()
                      if(value != 0) ....
                  }
}
```

seems like a pretty ugly way to do it. Whats a possible better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for {
    value, _ := FuncX()
    if value == 0 {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: @tommywild -- True, but you can always use a closure/function variable to reduce any function to having zero arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A more complex loop header than others have offered, although having nothing in the loop body may trigger coder OCD.

```
for value,_ := FuncX(); value != 0; value,_ = FuncX() {
}
```

In fact, this is usually how I read files line by line in Go

```
// Assume we have some bufio.Reader named buf already created
for line,err := buf.ReadString('\n'); err == nil; line,err = buf.ReadString('\n') {
    // Do stuff with the line.
}
```

If you need `line` or `err` outside the loop you just predeclare them and replace the `:=` with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop like:

```
value, _ := FuncX()
for value == 0 {
    value, _ = FuncX() // note using the = not :=
}
```